# averaging waveforms in matlab

Tags: matlab, waveform

I have a matrix that called 'allWaves' that is 32x5000.

Each of the 32 points represents a point on a wave. And there is 5000 waves. I was hoping to get one final averaged waveform.

this is what i've tried, i'm a beginner in Matlab. And I was really hoping to just plot this final wave. Thank you in advance.

```
finalIndices = [1:length(allWaves)];

for datapoint = 1:length(allWaves(:,1))
     AverageForm = [AverageForm mean(allWaves,finalIndices)];
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can average over a single dimension.

```
AverageForm = mean(allWaves, 2);
```

Comment: I know this is a lot, do you know how to calc std deviations?

Comment: `std(...,2)` As an FYI, if you highlight the function and hit f1 a help menu with all the syntaxes comes up.